# antlr4 don't match a string that I did't know

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to match this string: `ab.cd is` , but it does not match
Ant if I change `is` to `=` , it can match `ab.cd =`.

```
path :  PATHS 'is' ;
PATHS : FIELD('.'FIELD)*;
fragment INT : '0'..'9'+ ;
FIELD : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+|'*'|INT;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? When I run your example (after adding a pattern to ignore whitespace), it matches your input for me.

Comment: As Jeff said, I think that ignoring whitespaces could solve it.

Try this: 

WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;